# Declarative Authorization - syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization

Is this the correct way of saying that the permission should allow read access if both attributes on the first line OR the second line attribute is true? Thank you

```
has_permission_on :grant do
      to => :read
      if_attribute { :grant_application_opens < Date.today :join_by => :and       :grant_application_closes > Date.today } 
      if_attribute :grant_application_enduring => true
      end
```

Comment: if you want to make sure, that it does what you want, write a test for it. it's called explorative testing.

Comment: Thanks - I know the above is incorrect - but I can't find how to correct the errors.